# Why can't I connect to the internet via wired connection

Tags: networking

I've just resurrected an older PC to use as my linux box.
Before Installing Ubuntu I verified that the PC could connect to the internet.
I installed Ubuntu and am now not able to connect to the internet

In a shell I type `ifconfig` and receive:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:50:8d:74:90:a8  
    inet 6 addr: fe80::8dff:fe74:90a8/64 Scope:Link  
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1  
    CX packets:687 erros:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:81475 (81.4 KB) TX bytes:6050 (6.0 KB)
    Interrupt:18 Base address:0xb000
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|ethernet)"` returns:

```
02:0b.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp IC P1
us IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY [13f0:0200] (rev 31)
Subsystem: ABIT Computer Corp. Device [147b:1c08]
Kernel driver in use: sundance
Kernel modules: sundance
```

`uname -r` returns:

```
3.2.0-29-generic-pae
```

I am connected directly (hardwired, no wireless) to the router in my home office

`dmeg | grep eth0` returns:

```
[11.292409] eth0: IC Plus Corporation IP100A FAST Ethernet Adapter at 0001b000, 00:50:8d:74:90:a8, IRQ 18
[11.293132] eth0: MII PHY found at address 0, status 0x786d advertising 01e1.
[173.941125] ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[192.986492] eth0: Link up
[192.986895] eth0: Link changed: 100bps, full duplex
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We'll need more hardware information. Could you include the output of the following command run from a terminal? `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|ethernet)"` as well as `uname -r`

Comment: thanks gertvdijk  - additional info
02:0b.0 Ehternet controller [0200]: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp P1
us IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY [13f0:0200] (rev 31)
Subsystem ABIT Computer Corp. Device [147b:1c08]
Kernel driver in use: sundance
Kernel modules: sundance

uname -r gives back
3.2.0-29-generic-pae

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide new information. This is Q&A site, not a discussion forum, you see? :)

Comment: Please edit your question and tell what kind of connection you want  to achieve: via modem, router, corporate LAN?

Comment: Have you setup the connection in network manager? Seems like you didn't tell it to connect to the wired network. Just saying.

Comment: (posted as answer by [Vitor](http://askubuntu.com/users/125032/vitor)): Have you assigned an address to the interface, maybe through 'ifconfig', 'ip address', or 'dhcpcd'? Also, can you get a wired connection between other machines and the router? Maybe the problem is in the router's side.

Comment: I"ve solved the problem by installing an NIC rather than using the ethernet connection on the mother board.

Someone posted a comment on my question (that I can no longer see for some reason) that my problem sounded like a known bug with my network hardware. This prompted me to use a network card and it worked.

Thanks All!

Comment: @kohho I posted that because I *thought* it was that bug, but your `dmesg` output had no sign of of it. That's why I removed it, as it's not applicable on your device. But yeah, this integrated card is a very rare find and therefore not well tested I think. Good you solved the issue now, but could you post this as an answer to your own question? That is how this site works. I've posted a 'CW-answer' in the meantime. Feel free to post your own real answer and accept that one.

Answer (score 1):

I"ve solved the problem by installing an NIC rather than using the ethernet connection on the mother board. Someone posted a comment on my question (that I can no longer see for some reason) that my problem sounded like a known bug with my network hardware. This prompted me to use a network card and it worked. Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning an address to the interface, maybe through 'ifconfig', 'ip address', or 'dhcpcd'. Also, check to make sure that you can get a wired connection between other machines and the router--maybe the problem is in the router's side.